# Adding 'all' value to a foreign key form field based on model?

Tags: python, django, forms, filter

I am building a filter for my website where people can filter by cuisine. In order to achieve this I used a model form to receive input information that sets the filter variable in a query in my view. However as you can see in the image linked below, the default select for my cuisine categories is '-------' .

How would I go about changing this to say the words 'all' and setting a value so my filter queries everything for those categories? I think it has something to do with using a form method but I have been unable to understand what is actually happening in some of the examples.

[image]

Here is my simple code

Models

```
class Cuisine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views

```
def home_page(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = FilterForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cuisine = form.cleaned_data['cuisine']
            food = get_list_or_404(Food, cuisine__pk=cuisine.pk)
            return render('base.html', {'food': food, 'form':form})
    else:
        form = FilterForm()
    return render('base.html', {'form':form})
```

Form

```
class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cuisine
        fields = ('name')
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be your actual code. Cuisine doesn't have a choices field, so the form wouldn't render with a dropdown.

Comment: Sorry you're right, this screen shot was from my old code, my old stuff was a bit dirty. I need to add that back in. EDIT: Just checked my old code, this is actually exactly what I have except in the form, the model is set to Food. It does render the select dropdown.

Comment: Right, the Food model would render a dropdown, because it has a foreign key. Please can you update the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a modelform here. You only have one field, and you're not using it to create or edit instances of Food or Cuisine. It would be simpler to use a manual form with a ModelChoiceField, to which you can pass the [`empty_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) parameter.

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    cuisine = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cuisine.objects.all(),
                                     empty_label="All")
```

(Note you could do this with the ModelForm as well, but that just makes it even more pointless, as you are now not using any of the ModelForm functionality.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely see what you mean. I should only use modelform if I am adding or editing instances. I didn't realise it was so easy to add a multichoice field with all my cuisines.